# XPath query to get <li> elements below h2/h3 tags with keywords on span class attribute

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I have a structure HTML like the following:

```
<h3><span class="important">important 1</span></h3>
<ul><li>1</li></ul>
<ul><li>2</li></ul>

<h2><span class="important_2">important 2</span></h2>
<ul><li>3</li></ul>
<ul><li>4</li></ul>

<h3><span class="not_important">not important</span></h3>
<ul><li>5</li></ul>
<ul><li>6</li></ul>

<h2><span class="not_important_2">not important</span></h2>
<ul><li>7</li></ul>
<ul><li>8</li></ul>
```

I'm trying to get all `<li>` elements except those below `h2` or `h3` with class name with the keyword `not_important` on it but I don't really know how to go about it.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
In [1]: import scrapy

In [2]: selector = scrapy.Selector(text="""<h3><span class="important">important 1</span></h3>
   ...:     <ul><li>1</li></ul>
   ...:     <ul><li>2</li></ul>
   ...:     
   ...:     <h2><span class="important_2">important 2</span></h2>
   ...:     <ul><li>3</li></ul>
   ...:     <ul><li>4</li></ul>
   ...:     
   ...:     <h3><span class="not_important">not important</span></h3>
   ...:     <ul><li>5</li></ul>
   ...:     <ul><li>6</li></ul>
   ...:     
   ...:     <h2><span class="not_important_2">not important</span></h2>
   ...:     <ul><li>7</li></ul>
   ...:     <ul><li>8</li></ul>""")

In [3]: not_important = selector.xpath(".//span[contains(@class, 'not_important')]")

In [4]: not_important
Out[4]: 
[<Selector xpath=".//span[contains(@class, 'not_important')]" data=u'<span class="not_important">not importan'>,
 <Selector xpath=".//span[contains(@class, 'not_important')]" data=u'<span class="not_important_2">not import'>]
```

My idea was to get **all** `<li>` elements. Then get **all elements I don't want** using the above code in combination with `following-sibling::ul` (it doesn't work when I do `not_important[0].xpath("following-sibling::ul")`) And at the very end exclude everything I don't want from the `list` of every `<li>` element.

In other words, I'm stuck. Any help will be appreciated and Happy New Year,.

Comment: Do you know that there are only two `ul` elements after an `h3` or `h2` beforehand?

Comment: @alecxe no, there could be many and there's no way  to know how many

Comment: One more question: is it always that "important" elements are coming before "not important"?

Comment: @alecxe yes sir, all *important* elements comes before *not important* ones. Thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use a combination of [`preceding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding) and [`following`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following) to get every `ul` element between the "important" and "not important" elements:

```
//ul[preceding::span/@class ="important" and 
     following::span/@class = "not_important"]/li/text()
```

Works for me on the provided example input (extracts `['1', '2', '3', '4']`).